# Spring Boot doesn't override default property by profile property in Map

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a property with an array value that I want to override when a certain profile is active. But instead of replacing the property Spring Boot performs a strange merge of two arrays. It worked fine on Spring Boot version 1.5 but stopped after upgrading to version 2.5.

I have an `application.yml` that looks like this:

```
spring.config.use-legacy-processing: true

configuration:
    type:
        my-type:
            ... # some configuration properties
            my-list: ['first','second','third']

---
spring:
    profiles: dev

configuration:
    type:
        my-type:
            ... # some configuration properties
            my-list: ['fourth']
```

I am retrieving this configuration as `Map` and for property `my-list` when running with `dev` profile I am getting an array `['fourth','second','third']`. It is the default array with the first element replaced by the value from the profile configuration. If I would replace profile array with `['fourth','fifth']` then the result would be `['fourth','fifth','third']`.

I tried to disable legacy processing and use `spring.active.on-profile` it still works the same way.

If I am consuming properties to class instead of `Map` then everything works fine but the list of properties is not fixed.

Maybe someone knows what could be done about this?

Comment: I'm not a YAML expert, but doesn't your sequence need to be (spaces represent new lines + indent):
`my-list:
    - first
    - second
    - third` to be valid YAML? [Reference](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id857181)

Comment: Not necessarily, it could be just a list separated by commas in brackets, it gives the same result